# want to make exe file from .py

Tags: windows-7

I want to make an executable for my python file `xxx.py` (I have Python 3.6.1/Windows 7)

I tried with `pip install pyinstaller`. But I am getting error:

> "No connection can be made because target machine actively refused".

So my firewall is blocking it. Since it's an ofc pc, I don't want to unblock firewall.

I have admin rights.

So I downloaded PyInstaller-3.3.1. Now I am not sure how to install it. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

### The following is a guide on how to setup Pyinstaller on a Windows system when, due to firewall restrictions, you are not able to install it using pip...

Normally you would just install Pyinstaller with `pip` like so:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

In some instances this is not possible due to a firewall blocking you, such as corporate environments.
If installing using `pip` isn't an option you can download the [tarball](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/releases/download/v3.3.1/PyInstaller-3.3.1.tar.gz) from [pyinstaller.org](https://www.pyinstaller.org/downloads.html) and install it manually.

The download comes as a gzipped tarball, so you'll need a program like [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) to uncompress/extract it.

Once you have 7zip install, navigate to the location you downloaded the pyinstaller tarball to and right-click it and scroll down to 7zip > Extract Files. This will create a `dist` folder with one more tarball inside. So again right-click that and scroll down to `7zip > Extract Files`. This will create a folder called `Pyinstaller-3.3.1`. Make note of the full path name to the folder `Pyinstaller-3.3.1` and open a command prompt and change directories into that folder. From there run the following command:

```
python setup.py install
```

After the setup completes you should now have `pyinstaller.exe` in your `Python36\Scripts` folder (which should be either in `C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts` or `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts`, depending on whether you chose "for all users" or "just for this user" during the python install).

Before you can use Pyinstaller you'll also need to install `pywin32`. Again, normally the easiest way to install this is to simply run:

```
pip install pywin32
```

But in this case of a firewall blocking the pip install, you'll have to download and install pywin32 manually (pywin32 would have been automatically installed had you been able to install Pyinstaller the easy way with `pip`).
You can find the installation file for pywin32 at [github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases). Be sure download the correct version to match your version of python and the system's architecture. The installation for pywin32 is quick and straightforward.

Now you're ready to compile your first Python script to an `.exe` file.

If Python is already added to your environment variables, you can run the following command from any directory to compile your script

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile C:\Example\folder\your_script.py
```

Of course you'll change that example above to the actual path of your script. Note that Pyinstaller will create a `dist` folder with your new `.exe` file in whatever is your current directory when you run the pyinstaller command, so change directories to wherever you want to new folder/file to be outputted to before you run the pyinstaller command.

Also note that the `--onefile` option is not the only options but it's a good one to use as it creates a one-file bundled executable. For further reading about Pyinstaller's other options, see [Using PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html).

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked a long time ago. The answer is the same, but I want to make an addition to the previous answer.

If someone stumbles upon this question (like me) in search of an answer, then here's more information.

I did all this on 32-bit Windows XP and Python v3.4.
You may not have these problems, but just in case, I wrote about it.

PyInstaller will ask you to install some more packages (not just PiWin32).
Here's another list of the packages you need:

1. altgraph
2. macholib
3. pefile
   Pefyle will ask you to install "future".

In addition, PyWin32 may ask you to install another package "pypiwin32", if you are running on a 32-bit OS.

upd: I forgot to say that it MAY BE required to install not "pywin32" but "pywin32-ctypes"
P>S> The only problem I had was to find libraries for python of the version I needed - 3.4. But this problem is easy